# Group list by value

Tags: vb.net

I have a list, is called: `feedJobList`. This list contains Objects of `FeedJob`.

In each `FeedJob`, I have a parameter of: `belongsTo`

for example:

my list is:

```
[FeedJob1] - [[FeedJob2] - [FeedJob3]
```

while:

```
FeedJob1 contains:
    belongsTo: 1
    name: name1

FeedJob2:
    belongsTo: 2
    name: name2

FeedJob3:
    belongsTo: 1
    name: name3
```

I am trying to group it to list of list of objects by the value of `belongsTo`.

for this example, I want to get a new list that contains:

```
[ [FeedJob1, FeedJob3], [feedJob2] ]
```

`FeedJob1` and `FeedJob3` are in the same list because they have the same value of `belongsTo`.

I am not sure, but maybe it should be something like:

```
dim listOfLists = For Each item In feedJobList.GroupBy(Function(k)  K.belongsTo)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get a `List(Of List(Of FeedJob))` where each list in the list contains the same `belongsTo`?  Use `ToList()` on the group:

```
dim listOfLists As List(Of List(Of FeedJob)) = feedJobList.
    GroupBy(Function(fj) fj.belongsTo).
    Select(Function(g) g.ToList()).
    ToList()
```